# Any way that guest users see the site as registered users?

Tags: themes, redirect

My theme does a redirect when author profiles are given like this in author.php:

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}
```

Is there any way for wordpress to detect guest users as registered users without having to be registered to avoid this redirection? I can't use childtheme. Is there any snippet, htaccess or something?

Comment: Well is_user_logged_in is pluggable so you can replace it in a plugin with extra logic to return true always on an author page, or you could write a determine_current_user hook with a low priority to return a fake user if it's called on an author page too. But this is bound to cause some other problem somewhere so you really don't want to do this. Solve whatever technical or requirement problem you need to to get that code removed from your theme rather than trying to fight against it.

Comment: Or maybe your site also has a requirement to keep author pages away from scapers? Maybe you shouldn't be doing this.

Comment: Good Rup, the web is for adult content, I would give you the demo of the theme, but I do not think it is well seen here hehehe, I would not know how to do it with a complement or something, the truth is that you are right in fighting against the code, but the theme is destroyed with the child theme, that's why I have it complicated, I would have to remove the code every time it is updated

Comment: The developers do not respond to the tickets either, they have disappeared, so I have to fix it as I can on my own.